# MDX - Applying a month summary value to a dimension

Tags: mdx, calculated-field

I am trying to apply a measure value calculated at the Month level to a dimension contained within that month i.e.

[image: Before]

Should look like this:

[image: After]

I've attempted to use a scoping statement so far but with no luck.

```
SCOPE (
   {[Sale].[Sale Year].&[2]:[Sale].[Sale Year].&[7]}
            ,[Date].[Calendar Month].&[201603]
            ,[Measures].[Costs Per Sale] );

THIS = ([Date].[Calendar Month].&[201603],[Measures].[Costs Per Sale]);
END SCOPE;
```

The `Aggregated Sales` measure is calculated using the `Sale Year` which unfortunately has not and cannot be linked to the `Cost` dimension.

Does anyone know how I can apply the `Cost Per Sale` monthly value to the `[Sale].[Sale Year]` dimension?

Thanks

Comment: The only difference in the second pic is that Costs per Sales is repeating for every member. Is that what you want?

Comment: @SouravA Yes except [Date].[Calendar Month] and [Sale].[Sale Year] don't form a natural hierarchy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
SCOPE ({[Sale].[Sale Year].&[2]:[Sale].[Sale Year].&[7]} ,[Measures].[Costs Per Sale]);    
THIS = ([Sale].[Sale Year].[All],[Measures].[Costs Per Sale]);
END SCOPE;
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you very much. So simple and it's be driving me mad